# how to email multiple rows of order details

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a code which is used to upload form data to mysql and also email the user. this code works perfectly but it is sending only the last item details of order not all items please tell me how to do this.
this code is works under a `.inc` file
here is my portion of email code in `sales_order_db.inc` file

```
$time = date("d/m/y  H:i:s", time());

 $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM balance_report WHERE Reg_No IN ($order->customer_id)");

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
$balance = $row1['Balance'];
$tbalance = $balance - $total;
  } 

$from = 'from: smartcard@lotus.edu.in'; 
$to = $order->delivery_address; 
$subject = ("Rs: " . $total . ' , Debit - SmartCard'); 
$emailBody="";

$emailBody .= ("Dear,  " . $order->deliver_to . "\r\n" . "\r\n"  . " \r\n"."Tran. No              :  " . $tran . "\r\n" . "Debit Amount   :  Rs  " . $total . "\r\n" . "Balance                :  Rs  " . $tbalance . "\r\n" . "Date                      :  " . $time . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "

For more details login to http://162.9.9.9/smartcard" . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "Thanks," . "\r\n" . "Lotus Institute of Management.");

$emailBody .= "$line->stock_id"."$line->item_description"."$line->price"."$line->quantity"; 

mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $from);
```

this line`$emailBody .= "$line->stock_id"."$line->item_description"."$line->price"."$line->quantity";` is sending only the last row of items but not all rows, i want to send all order details.

this my sql statement

```
foreach ($order->line_items as $line)
    {
        if ($loc_notification == 1 && is_inventory_item($line->stock_id))
        {
            $sql = "SELECT ".TB_PREF."loc_stock.*, ".TB_PREF."locations.location_name, ".TB_PREF."locations.email
                FROM ".TB_PREF."loc_stock, ".TB_PREF."locations
                WHERE ".TB_PREF."loc_stock.loc_code=".TB_PREF."locations.loc_code
                AND ".TB_PREF."loc_stock.stock_id = '" . $line->stock_id . "'
                AND ".TB_PREF."loc_stock.loc_code = '" . $order->Location . "'";
            $res = db_query($sql,"a location could not be retreived");
            $loc = db_fetch($res);
            if ($loc['email'] != "")
            {
                $qoh = get_qoh_on_date($line->stock_id, $order->Location);
                $qoh -= get_demand_qty($line->stock_id, $order->Location);
                $qoh -= get_demand_asm_qty($line->stock_id, $order->Location);
                $qoh -= $line->quantity;
                if ($qoh < $loc['reorder_level'])
                {
                    $st_ids[] = $line->stock_id;
                    $st_names[] = $line->item_description;
                    $st_num[] = $qoh - $loc['reorder_level'];
                    $st_reorder[] = $loc['reorder_level'];
                }
            }
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".TB_PREF."sales_order_details (order_no, trans_type, stk_code, description, unit_price, quantity, discount_percent) VALUES (";
        $sql .= $order_no . ",".$order->trans_type .
                ",".db_escape($line->stock_id).", "
                .db_escape($line->item_description).", $line->price,
                $line->quantity,
                $line->discount_percent)";
        db_query($sql, "order Details Cannot be Added");
```

here is the full code of file

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function add_sales_order(&$order)
{
    global $loc_notification, $path_to_root, $Refs;

    begin_transaction();
    hook_db_prewrite($order, $order->trans_type);
    $order_no = get_next_trans_no($order->trans_type);
    $del_date = date2sql($order->due_date);
    $order_type = 0; // this is default on new order
    $total = $order->get_trans_total();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".TB_PREF."sales_orders (order_no, type, debtor_no, trans_type, branch_code, customer_ref, reference, comments, ord_date,
        order_type, ship_via, deliver_to, delivery_address, contact_phone,
        freight_cost, from_stk_loc, delivery_date, payment_terms, total)
        VALUES (" .db_escape($order_no) . "," .db_escape($order_type) . "," . db_escape($order->customer_id) .
         ", " .db_escape($order->trans_type) . "," .db_escape($order->Branch) . ", ".
            db_escape($order->cust_ref) .",". 
            db_escape($order->reference) .",". 
            db_escape($order->Comments) .",'" . 
            date2sql($order->document_date) . "', " .
            db_escape($order->sales_type) . ", " .
            db_escape($order->ship_via)."," . 
            db_escape($order->deliver_to) . "," .
            db_escape($order->delivery_address) . ", " .
            db_escape($order->phone) . ", " . 
            db_escape($order->freight_cost) .", " . 
            db_escape($order->Location) .", " .
            db_escape($del_date) . "," .
            db_escape($order->payment) . "," .
            db_escape($total). ")";

    db_query($sql, "order Cannot be Added");

    $order->trans_no = array($order_no=>0);

    if ($loc_notification == 1)
    {
        include_once($path_to_root . "/inventory/includes/inventory_db.inc");
        $st_ids = array();
        $st_names = array();
        $st_num = array();
        $st_reorder = array();
    }
    foreach ($order->line_items as $line)
    {
        if ($loc_notification == 1 && is_inventory_item($line->stock_id))
        {
            $sql = "SELECT ".TB_PREF."loc_stock.*, ".TB_PREF."locations.location_name, ".TB_PREF."locations.email
                FROM ".TB_PREF."loc_stock, ".TB_PREF."locations
                WHERE ".TB_PREF."loc_stock.loc_code=".TB_PREF."locations.loc_code
                AND ".TB_PREF."loc_stock.stock_id = '" . $line->stock_id . "'
                AND ".TB_PREF."loc_stock.loc_code = '" . $order->Location . "'";
            $res = db_query($sql,"a location could not be retreived");
            $loc = db_fetch($res);
            if ($loc['email'] != "")
            {
                $qoh = get_qoh_on_date($line->stock_id, $order->Location);
                $qoh -= get_demand_qty($line->stock_id, $order->Location);
                $qoh -= get_demand_asm_qty($line->stock_id, $order->Location);
                $qoh -= $line->quantity;
                if ($qoh < $loc['reorder_level'])
                {
                    $st_ids[] = $line->stock_id;
                    $st_names[] = $line->item_description;
                    $st_num[] = $qoh - $loc['reorder_level'];
                    $st_reorder[] = $loc['reorder_level'];
                }
            }
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".TB_PREF."sales_order_details (order_no, trans_type, stk_code, description, unit_price, quantity, discount_percent) VALUES (";
        $sql .= $order_no . ",".$order->trans_type .
                ",".db_escape($line->stock_id).", "
                .db_escape($line->item_description).", $line->price,
                $line->quantity,
                $line->discount_percent)";
        db_query($sql, "order Details Cannot be Added");

    // Now mark quotation line as processed
        if ($order->trans_type == ST_SALESORDER && $line->src_id)
            update_parent_line(ST_SALESORDER, $line->src_id, $line->qty_dispatched); // clear all the quote despite all or the part was ordered
    } /* inserted line items into sales order details */
    add_audit_trail($order->trans_type, $order_no, $order->document_date);
    $Refs->save($order->trans_type, $order_no, $order->reference);

    hook_db_postwrite($order, $order->trans_type);
    commit_transaction();

    if ($loc_notification == 1 && count($st_ids) > 0)
    {
        require_once($path_to_root . "/reporting/includes/class.mail.inc");
        $company = get_company_prefs();
        $mail = new email($company['coy_name'], $company['email']);
        $from = $company['coy_name'] . " <" . $company['email'] . ">";
        $to = $loc['location_name'] . " <" . $loc['email'] . ">";
        $subject = _("Stocks below Re-Order Level at " . $loc['location_name']);
        $msg = "\n";
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($st_ids); $i++)
            $msg .= $st_ids[$i] . " " . $st_names[$i] . ", " . _("Re-Order Level") . ": " . $st_reorder[$i] . ", " . _("Below") . ": " . $st_num[$i] . "\n";
        $msg .= "\n" . _("Please reorder") . "\n\n";
        $msg .= $company['coy_name'];
        $mail->to($to);
        $mail->subject($subject);
        $mail->text($msg);
        $ret = $mail->send();
    }
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 0_debtor_trans WHERE order_ IN ($order_no-1) and type = '10'");

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
  {
echo $row2['trans_no'];
$tra = $row2['trans_no'];
$tran = $tra +1;
}

$time = date("d/m/y  H:i:s", time());

 $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM balance_report WHERE Reg_No IN ($order->customer_id)");

while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
$balance = $row1['Balance'];
$tbalance = $balance - $total;
  } 

$from = 'from: smartcard@lotus.edu.in'; 
$to = $order->delivery_address; 
$subject = ("Rs: " . $total . ' , Debit - SmartCard'); 
$emailBody="";

$emailBody .= ("Dear,  " . $order->deliver_to . "\r\n" . "\r\n"  . " \r\n"."Tran. No              :  " . $tran . "\r\n" . "Debit Amount   :  Rs  " . $total . "\r\n" . "Balance                :  Rs  " . $tbalance . "\r\n" . "Date                      :  " . $time . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "

For more details login to http://162.9.9.9/smartcard" . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "\r\n" . "Thanks," . "\r\n" . "Lotus Institute of Management.");

$emailBody .= "$line->stock_id"."$line->item_description"."$line->price"."$line->quantity"; 

mail($to, $subject, $emailBody, $from);
    return $order_no;
}
```

Comment: How u are generating the $line data ?

Comment: Check my edit i have added sql statement

Comment: How does the code you have posted now relate to the code you posted before? They seem to have little to do with each other.

Comment: Check my edit i have added full code of file

Comment: You are lopping the ($order->line_items as $line) so u need to generate the body html there as $line_html = ''; before the loop and then inside the loop $line_html .=  "$line->stock_id"."$line->item_description"."$line->price"."$line->quantity<br />"; finally use this $emailBody .=  $line_html and remove $emailBody .= "$line->stock_id"."$line->item_description"."$line->price"."$line->quantity"; line

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
  {
$balance = $row1['Balance'];
$tbalance = $balance - $total;
  }
```

that's why you are getting the last result, you need calculate total balance in while, and then use that when sending.